# How to know from where the website is being operated?

Tags: dns-domain, web-hosting, websites

I mean one can find their host server (from which the domain name is bought), but can we check who bought the domain and from where is that website is being hosted?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some information from sites like who.is: http://who.is/whois/stackexchange.com, [IP ownership](http://who.is/whois-ip/ip-address/198.252.206.140) and [ip2location.com](http://www.ip2location.com/demo) but this information can be protected from the public or in case of location of the IP address, it can be wrong.